# Need help in developing a mysql view that would split the comma seperated row value

Tags: mysql, split

Am trying to find a method to develop a view that would split 'col1' data based on comma. Example format below,

Master table,

```
col1            |    col2        |   col3

SN,MD,DE        |  T            |   0

AF,SU            |  F           |   1
```

View should look like below,

```
col1  |   col2   |  col3

SN    |    T     |   0

MD    |    T     |   0

DE    |    T     |   0

AF    |    F     |   1

SU    |    F      |  1
```

Tried to build it using function, functions works well in splitting it & dumping the required rows on a temp table. But am not able to successfully incorporate that function into "create view SQL".  Any suggestions would be helpful. Am pasting the body section of the function alone,

```
create function rpt(string, string, int)

.....

SET retval = '';

SET integ = inte;

SET i = 0;

SET num = LENGTH(stri)-LENGTH(REPLACE(stri,deli,''));

IF LENGTH(stri) = 0 THEN

RETURN '';

END IF;

WHILE ( i <= num ) DO

IF num = 0 THEN

SET retval = stri;

insert into temprpt values(integ,retval,flg);

ELSE

SET retval = book01d.split(i, deli, stri);

insert into temprpt values(integ,retval,flg);

END IF;

SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;

RETURN v;

END
```

The split function inside this function would help splitting the comma separated values. So on a final note, am able to split the values & dump it into temprpt table. Now we need to call this function & at the same time read from the temp table as well.

Thanks,
Dharmaraj.G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly access this without using view

```
SELECT master_tbl.col3,master_tbl.col2
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(master_tbl.col2, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)       
col1 FROM
(SELECT 1 n UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) numbers INNER JOIN master_tbl
ON CHAR_LENGTH(master_bl.col1)
-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(master_tbl.col1, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY col3, n;
```

Here In ON condition we are just join our master_tbl table to derived table numbers so only those who have this condition true joined.
**Note** :- This only work under 5 comma if you want for more comma you have to ad more union select.

Comment: Thanks jai for the quick turnaround, it worked as expected. Am not able to understand the ON condition mentioned for the join. Can you brief a little on that.

Comment: thanks, got it. and yes i expanded upto select 17 to accommodate my master table content..